# How to write 2 calculations in one Cell in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have **GPA** and I want the cell just shows me if the student is passed or failed without showing the GPA as number.

Can I?

Comment: What is GPA? Give me a link about it

Comment: GPA means grade point average. That being said, I don't see the problem here. It's just one formula...?

Answer (score 2):

Is it?

```
=IF(A3<2;"FAIL";"PASS")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the GPA in the first part of the If:
**If(Average(A1:D1)<10,"Fail","Pass")**
Average(A1:D1) is the formula of calculated GPA where the data is in A1:D1 for the same student you can change it depending on your data and formula, I suppose 10 is the limit of fail and pass so GPA < 10 means Fail, and GPA >=10 means pass also you can change it like you want and write the formula in E1 and drag it down